# Oracle Ole DB drivers won't work: ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, odbc, connection-string

I've installed three of the client packages on Windows Server 2008 Standard but still cannot open a connection because of the error "Provider not found". All of these packages are for 64bit.

C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe screenshot:

[image: This is the C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe result]

c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe screenshot: NO ORACLE DRIVER!!!

[image]

```html
<%  
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=XXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Data Source=XXXX"
%>
```

When I run the code, it gives an error:

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'
>
> Provider not found.

I've also read similar questions and did what they suggest but I'm stuck at this error.

32bit app pool is also enabled.

[image]

Connection string help page: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/

Oracle 11g release 2 client ODBC drivers link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html

Comment: Oh, thanks, disabling 32bit support solved my probled, duh!

Comment: `ODBC` and `OLE DB` are different providers. According your code you use `OLE DB`, that has **nothing** to do with drivers ODBC listed in `odbcad32.exe`.

Comment: I'm gonna edit the title...

Comment: Also the first and second screenshot are not related to any OLE DB Provider

Comment: A similar question is mentioned them. Better I'll keep them for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Provider for OLE DB** should be installed and **OraOLEDB12.DLL** should be registered. You can use free **RegDllView** utility from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html) to examine.

[image]

Download and install ODAC.

> Oracle Provider for OLE DB 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for
>   Windows x64
>
> [Released October 5, 2015]
>
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

---

> Disable 32bit support in IIS application pool.

---

> Reboot